# How to Write a Bash Script that Will React to Ceph Cluster based on Watch Output for Linux

Tags: python, bash, shell, automation, ceph

So here is the problem I am facing: I have a Ceph cluster that is undergoing a balance, but occasionally I get a Slow Requests message from the ceph -s output. I have two terminals open to the ceph cluster. One terminal is set to active watch for slow requests using the following command:

```sh
watch "ceph -s | grep -i 'slow'"
```

As a result, I am seeing two outcomes appear.
One the Output looks like this:

```sh
Every 2.0s: ceph -s | grep -i 'slow'          Sun Jul 12 02:17:49 2020

            107 slow requests are blocked > 32 sec. Implicated osds 17
,27,37,51,58,81,118,122,124,137,153,160,181,197,205,217,236,259,267,28
3,309,318,323,328,343
```

At this point if I see slow requests pop in I need to immediately set the cluster to the following:

```sh
rbarrett@osd001:~$ sudo ceph osd set norecover
norecover is set
```

After which the slow requests will eventually disappear and you will have to set the cluster to continue with recovery.

```sh
Every 2.0s: ceph -s | grep -i 'slow'          Sun Jul 12 02:20:07 2020
```

After the `slow requests` disappear I have to unset the `norecover` option

```sh
rbarrett@osd001:~$ sudo ceph osd unset norecover
norecover is unset
```

So here is my question: How can I write a script in bash to run as a process or service to do this for me?

My first thought would be to use a variable for that watch command, but then how can I set the script to run and keep an eye on the cluster?

I don't mind using python but would prefer a bash script.

I was thinking of using something like this, but I don't know if it would continually run.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
check=$(ceph -s | grep -i "slow requests")
echo $check
if [[ -n $check   ]];then
  echo "setting norecover flag"
  sudo ceph osd set norecover
else
  echo "no slow requests"
  sudo ceph osd unset norecover
fi
```

Someone please confirm if this will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop around your script to run it infinitely.

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do
    if sudo ceph -s | grep -i "slow requests"; then
        echo "setting norecover flag"
        sudo ceph osd set norecover
    else
        echo "no slow requests"
        sudo ceph osd unset norecover
    fi
    
    sleep 2
fi
```

I have added a 2-second sleep between the checks to avoid high CPU usage with *this* script (which could otherwise contribute to the cluster load significantly). You may want to adjust this based on your need (I'd suggest to *not* lower than 2 seconds).